# Android 11<= resolveActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, resolveactivity

I work on improvement functionality for android app. There is a feature for making photo from app. And for andorid 11<=

takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())

returns null. I know it's because of higher android version. But when I removed if statement everything working so I wonder why this line was there and what wrong could happened if it will be removed.

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
   //if (true) {
        File photoFile = createImageFile();

        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with resolveActivity prior to trying to launch an URL in Android 11.  There's some info here: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no matching activity, your `startActivityForResult()` call should crash with an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Wrapping the `startActivityForResult()` call in a `try`/`catch` works for all Android versions.

Comment: I have a similar question posted for resolveActivity() here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74282516/android-add-resolveactivity-as-well-as-default-apps-setpackage-code.  Any thoughts or ideas for the question?