# Android: add resolveActivity() as well as default app's setPackage() code?

Tags: android-intent, sms, telephony

For API 19+, having a default app became available, so a null check for the default app could then occur.  My question is, once an Intent is set to the default app using setPackage(), is it still worthwhile to use a resolveActivity() null check on the Intent or is that redundant or overkill?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

    String defaultSMSPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this);
    final Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

    if (defaultSMSPackageName != null) {

        smsIntent.setPackage(defaultSMSPackageName);
        **if (smsIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)** {
              startActivity(smsIntent);
              finish();
        }
    }    
}
```

or just use this:

```
    ...  

    if (defaultSMSPackageName != null) {

        smsIntent.setPackage(defaultSMSPackageName);
        startActivity(smsIntent);
        finish();
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a situation like this, I would never use `resolveActivity()`. It doesn't solve all problems (e.g., `SecurityException` when trying to start the other activity). I would just wrap the `startActivity()` call in `try`/`catch`.

Something like `resolveActivity()` can be useful in places where you need to know that the other activity is unavailable *before* you try starting it. For example, perhaps you want to disable some button based on whether the other activity is available. Still, you should wrap the `startActivity()` call in `try`/`catch`. And bear in mind that on Android 11+ you will need to deal with package visibility rules for `resolveActivity()` to work.